# bindParam prepare query with IN

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

Такой вариант - работает:

```
$proba = "114";

$up1 = $conn->prepare("UPDATE b1d SET mycolumn = TRUE WHERE id_b IN (:id_b);");

$up1->bindParam(':id_b', $proba);
```

Если `$proba = "114,116,118";`, то уже не работает.

Как правильно сделать?

PostgreSQL 9.2.4, compiled by Visual C++ build 1600, 32-bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Постгрес тут не при чем. Именованные плейсхолдеры вида `:name` - это фишка PDO.

Поскольку плейсхолдер в PDO может представлять [только строковый или числовой литерал](http://phpfaq.ru/pdo#in), то каждое значение должно быть представлено собственным плейсхолдером. То есть, запрос должен получиться вида

```
IN (?,?,?)
```

и при исполнении в него должны передаваться значения по отельности. Это можно сделать таким кодом:

```
$proba = array(114,116,118);
$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($proba) - 1) . '?';
$sql = "UPDATE b1d SET mycolumn = TRUE WHERE id_b IN ($in)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)->execute($proba);
```

Не слшком красиво, но других вариантов, увы, нет.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, сейчас попробую.

Comment: Да, Ваш вариант работает и в моих условиях. Я правильно понял, что это такой же 'защищенный' вариант, как и с bindParam и ничем не хуже ?

Comment: Так никаких условий особенных здесь и нету, все стандартно.

Comment: Я имел ввиду, что можно на сервер отправить не массив, а готовую строку '114,116,118' и подставить в запросе UPDATE ... IN (".$proba.") , но это не рекомендуют, сори, нет опыта.

Comment: А, это конечно. Не то что не рекомендуют, а в принципе запрещено.

Comment: Я просто хотел уточнить Ваш комментарий про "никаких условий особенных здесь и нету", имелось ввиду нет 'защиты', или это касалось, что пример стандартный, но ничем не уступает bindParam.

Comment: А, понял. Да, этот вариант не хуже, а значительно лучше. Главное все переменные подставлять через плейсхолдеры - именно это обеспечивает безопасность. А привязывать через bindParam() или execute() - это уже дело вкуса. Но второй вариант значительно короче, поэтому execute() следует всегда предпочесть bindParam() .

Comment: Понял, спасибо - помогли.